# how to scroll in a mobile application when there is no scrolling bar using selenium in java

Tags: android, selenium, automation, webdriver, appium

Can you please help me with the code to scroll down in a mobile application which does not have a scrolling bar.

We are using angularJS with  cordova application to create hybrid app.

We are using appium to do mobile testing.

Comment: Can you please clarify, maybe with a code snippet or an illustration of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Aleksandar, we have a mobile app which does not have a scroll bar on different pages. As it is a mobile application, and we can manually swipe with a finger to scroll down. There is no scroll element locator. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: @richiegulati - can you please share your selenium code which you have done for scrolling try?

Answer (score 0):

```
var initTop = 0;
var initLeft = 0;

element(by.css('[ui-sref=".lam"]')).getLocation().then(function(navDivLocation) {
    initTop = navDivLocation.y;
    initLeft = navDivLocation.x;
```

browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(initTop, initLeft);').then(function() {

});

```
});
```

**initTop and initLeft are pixel points**

Comment: Hi Rajana, Thanks for replying!!But we are using the same code which you mentioned above but we need to check the same in different devices. As different devices will have different resolution, the pixel point does not work. Is there any other way we can resolve this issue?

Comment: This is working but it is not stopping on the element which I want to focus on rather scrolling to the end on the device.

Comment: the element locator code must write with in browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(initTop, initLeft);').then(function() {

}); block.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the swipe action, for example:

```
 driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration);
```

You can get the coordinates from the mobile device (developer option -> pointer location).